# Rapidminer : converting unix timestamp

Tags: r, rapidminer

Does anybody know a way to convert unix timestamp to date_time attribute?

I tried to use R extensions (my operators are mainly written in R) such as as.POSIXct functions to convert timestamps but it seems that rapidminer doesn't like it and keeps ignoring it.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  It would be helpful if you could elaborate on this.  It's hard to diagnose "doesn't like it".  What is letting you know it doesn't like it?  Sharing that info would be helpful.  A repoducible example is also very helpful.  Have a look at http://bit.ly/SORepro

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem is that once you imported a data table in rapidminer that contains a unix timestamp, the timestamp is recognized as numerical attribute not as data_time as it should be. Actually I found out that a way to convert a unix time is to generate another attribute using the "generate attribute" operator and the date_parse() function like this: date_parse(unixtimestamp*1000). I'd love to hear simpler/other solutions though (maybe including R apposite script to do so).

Answer (score 4):

A little known feature of generating attributes is that the input attribute can be the output attribute so no new one is created. In addition, the type of the attribute is changed.

In other words, a construction like this would work as long as the input is milliseconds since the epoch.

unixtime = date_parse(unixtime)